# a Framework is using a library I am using

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I am managing my library with cocoapod.

and there are some dependency,
a third party library CocoaAsyncSocket is other library's dependency.

Library A and B both linked to CocoaAsyncSocket.

and now I am going to use another framework. (Framework C)
Since it is compiled, when I build my App, it shows duplicate symbols.
since Framework C is using CocoaAsyncSocket too.

what is the best solution for this situation?

do I need to make a new branch for CocoaAsyncSocket to rename those class so It wont duplicate with Framework C??

Comment: You can remove CocoaAsyncSocket from any of your framework then it will work fine. Or if CocoaAsyncSocket does have few classes then you can rename otherwise its a big task or confusion for your project.

Comment: I would not recommend renaming any pods classes. what will happen when it'll be updated, you will do this manually each time?